# return value from string function in angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to implement a function in an **Angular service** which returns a `x` value, and then retrieve the value in any component. I am using native storage to store the value and then I need to access it from everywhere so making an angular server is the best way.

This is my **current implementation** but when I try to get the value in a page, this return me an undefined value:

```html
getValue() {
let x;
        this
            .functionUtil
            .getItems('someValue')
            .then(items => {
                if (items && items.length != 0) {
                    x= items[0];
                }
            });
            return x;
    }
```

Find below source of `functionUtil.getItems` function(`functionUtil` is a service with utility functions)

```html
getItems(ITEMS_KEY): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.storage.get(ITEMS_KEY);
  }
```

this is my page:

```html
   value: any;
 constructor(
    private myService: MyService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.value = this.myService.getValue();
    console.log(this.value) // this return undefined


  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Inside the service, print the items you get on the function Utils. Right after the .then(items => { console.log(JSON.stringfy(items)) ....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because the Promise is asynchrounous. Chronologically, the following happens: `x` is declared, `x` is returned (value is undefined), Promise resolves and changes the `x` inside the function but as undefined is already returned, it does effectively nothing.

The best way would be to return a new Promise holding your value from that method.

```
getValue() {
  return this
    .functionUtil
    .getItems('someValye')
    .then(items => {
      if (items && items.length != 0) {
        return items[0];
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    });
}
```

or using async-await:

```
async getValue() {
  const items = await this
    .functionUtil
    .getItems('someValye');

  if (items && items.length != 0) {
    return items[0];
  } 
}
```

*component*

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.value = await this.myService.getValue();
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's why you make a async operation. 
Rewrite it like this:

```
getValue(): Promise<any> {
  return this
            .functionUtil
            .getItems('someValye')
            .then(items => items && items.length != 0
                ? items[0] : null);

    }
```

And subscribe in component OnInit:

```
this.myService.getValue().then(value => this.value = value) ;
```

Or you could use async await :) like in comment above

Just keep in mind that it may take some time to Promise resolve, depends on your logic. Also you can use Promise directly in Template with async pipe :

```
{{value | async}}
```